# 2 Active Sessions in One Server - Codeigniter 2.2.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a project that needs to revise the whole back end. Currently, I've done a 50% of it and deployed live. Both application are working in one domain, different session but same data.

The problem is that, some page have shown a different account and items. E.g: If the client logged in and his/her id is 3, he/she had viewed the items and account details of different id.

The weird and most difficult part of this issue is that, the error is not always visible either mine. I dont have encountered this error on my unit. I have implemented this, worked from my local and deploy on live, and everything seems working very well. The error was continuously reporting by the client itself.

My question is that, is this a cause of 2 different session in one domain? Is there anyone who already encountered this and already solved? Please I need your help.

Massive thanks to you all guys in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Codeigniter applications on the same domain in itself shouldn't be a problem, as this is a supported [feature](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/managing_apps.html).  However, in your context, your issue may be how you have session set up between the two applications.  Make sure in each application that the `sess_cookie_name` is different.  This is configured within /application/config/config.php ([docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html)).  My first thought would be that if you have session crossing between your two applications, they are sharing the same cookie rather than being independent of each other.  The default value for this setting is `ci_session`, so if you haven't changed it on at least one of your applications, this is likely the cause of your problem.

-- Edit -- 
If you are using database storage for your sessions (`sess_use_database` set to TRUE), another possible solution would be to use different table names for the two sessions.  Inside config.php, there is another setting of `sess_table_name`.  Try making this different between the two applications.  The table structure would be the same, but with two different tables perhaps that would help keep the sessions from crossing.

If you aren't using the database, or if the different names still doesn't work, the next best idea I have would be to make them use the same session, but use different variable names between the two sides.  So rather than something like clientId on both, you could do clientIda and cliendIdb.

Comment: Thanks so much @justanotherprogrammer. Yes, the sess_cookie_name is the same to the other one. I try to do what you said and hopefully it will work. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @justanotherprogrammer, the problem still exist. Not sure if it's because of server. Is there a possibility that the server can't hold a multiple session? I don't have a deep knowledge about server itself, it is only my guess.

Comment: My next idea was too big for a comment, so see the edit to my original answer.